# Play audio as fast as possible in GStreamer

Tags: c++, c, audio-streaming, gstreamer-1.0

I'm new to GStreamer, so sorry if it's kind of a dumb question, but how can I stream audio data through my pipeline as fast as possible?

I use a playbin, and I have a bunch of songs that I'd like to send through it at the greatest speed available. I'm aware of the concept of frame stepping, I also read this tutorial: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/playback-speed.html, but still can't figure out how to do this simply without keyboard handling. Can someone explain it to me?